# How do I share and play music in my office?

Tags: music, sharing

I would like to use my old Macbook that is hooked up to stereo equipment, as a media server to allow everybody in my office to play or upload music, jukebox style.

The best case would be a web interface where I can change the music, an upload feature is not mandatory.

A solution using Ubuntu would be fine too. :)

Answer (score 2):

Check out '[play](http://zachholman.com/screencast/play/)' from one of the guys at GitHub. Ive had an interest in it, but never had a chance to use it yet.

Answer (score 2):

iTunes has this feature built in. Turn on iTunes DJ and let it play. Individuals using the [Remote app](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/remote/id284417350?mt=8) (iTunes App Store link) can vote for the next song, or outright start the next song.

It's not a universal app, but being an iPhone/iPod app means at least it can run on iPads as well.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tried it (was interested by your question so I googled around) but **[Subsonic](http://www.subsonic.org)** looks like a winner imho. Free download available for Windows, Mac, Linux and Unix.

> Subsonic is a free, web-based media streamer, providing ubiquitous access to your music. Use it to share your music with friends, or to listen to your own music while at work. You can stream to multiple players simultaneously, for instance to one player in your kitchen and another in your living room.

From the [features](http://www.subsonic.org/pages/features.jsp) page :

> Upload and download files to/from Subsonic, with automatic zipping and unzipping.

Comment: looks good i gonna check it out! [XBMC](http://xbmc.org/download/) looks good too.

Comment: i see XBMC more as a all-in-one solution (video files manager too) but keep us informed of your tests

Comment: i tried Subsonic, but to be honest the interface is... well... really bad. looks like typo 3 :). but it works as expected !